# Sublime couldn't find Node.js

Tags: node.js, macos, sublimetext3

I have had this very same problem happen with another Sublime Package - something isn't configured correctly on my Mac.

I installed CSSComb with `npm install -g csscomb`.

I installed the CssComb Sublime package using Sublime's "Package Installer".

I've restarted Sublime.

When I try to use CSSComb in Sublime, the console has the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 818, in run_
return self.run(edit)
File "/Users/alan/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/CSScomb/CSScomb.py", line 35, in run
combed = self.comb(originalBuffer, syntax, config)
File "/Users/alan/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/CSScomb/CSScomb.py", line 48, in comb
'$PATH by running `node -v` in your command-line.')
Exception: Couldn't find Node.js. Make sure it's in your $PATH by running `node -v` in your command-line.`
```

Running `node -v` outputs `v7.0.0`

Running `echo $PATH` outputs:
`/Users/alan/.nvm/versions/node/v7.0.0/bin:/Users/alan/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Within Sublime I have modified the path to node in the CSSComb configuration file:

`"node-path" : "/Users/alan/.nvm/versions/node/v7.0.0/bin",`

Still get the same error in Sublime console.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [README](https://github.com/csscomb/sublime-csscomb#caveats):

> If node has been installed with NVM you need to make a symlink to node in `/usr/local/bin`. Using OS X, the binary path would typically be `/Users/[your name]/.nvm/[node version]/bin/node`.

Open terminal and run the following:

```
sudo ln -s /Users/alan/.nvm/versions/node/v7.0.0/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
```

Then change the CSSComb settings file to:

```js
"node-path": ":/usr/local/bin", // the colon ":" is important!
```

and see if that works.

Comment: Suppose you already had node installed under `/usr/local/bin`. What might you try in that scenario?

Comment: @kendfss then you don't need to run the `sudo ln ...` command, just edit the CSSComb settings like I showed.

Comment: Thanks, it was a different plugin without that particular option but in the end I just put `os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/usr/local/bin"` near the top of every file that used either `os.environ` or `os.getenv`. They reference the same underlying dictionary, so there was no need to be too fussy.