# Sublime text cannot find Node.js. How do I help Sublime find Node properly?

Tags: node.js, macos, sublimetext, nvm, n

**The story:**

I had installed `n` about a month back while playing around with creating an Eslint config on my Mac, which was when Sublime Text started giving me problems, specifically with Eslint via Sublime linter. I had a bit of a break so I didn't attempt to fix the issue until last week, which was when I uninstalled `n` and installed `nvm` thinking that the issue was `n`. I then started getting the cannot find node error when I save any file in Sublime. Since then I had uninstalled `nvm` and `node.js` in hopes to start from scratch and fix the issue. I re-installed `nvm` and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193673/sublime-couldnt-find-node-js), stating the issues that `nvm` creates with changing the path for `node.js` on my machine. I tried the fix that was given, which was to create a link between the `nvm` path to node and `usr/local/bin/node` but that didn't work either. I have since uninstalled `nvm` in hopes that just having good old `node.js` installed by itself to do the trick. Still no luck.

**The error**:

> Couldn't find Node.js. Make sure it's in your $PATH by running `node -v` in your command-line.

Which is an alert from the Sublime app that only happens when I try to save a file.

**Other things I have tried:**

Updating my `.bash_profile` to make sure my `PATH` was correct. Updating my `.bash_exports` to make sure my `PATH` and `NODE_PATH` are correct. Updated my machine to macOS Sierra.

**In iTerm:**

`node -v` returns `v11.3.0`

`which node` returns `/usr/local/bin/node`

`echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/node`

`echo $NODE_PATH` returns `/usr/local/bin/node`

Note: I don't want to uninstall Sublime as this is on my work machine and it's a pain in the butt to deal with IT with the sublime license.

Answer (score 0):

After un-installing everything and re-installing everything, nothing worked. I gave up on `n` or `nvm` for the time being, and completely un-installed them. I even uninstalled Sublime and reinstalled it. The last thing I did was un-install and re-install sublimelinter eslint, which seemed to fix the issue. I'm not sure if that was really the fix, because I had already done that multiple times. The issue is resolved for the time being. I will update if the issue resurfaces.